# How can one use Webhooks from Paypal in its django application

Tags: python, django, paypal

I'm using `django-paypal` and `paypalrestsdk` to integrate **Paypal payment** & **subscriptions** to my website.

I've looked over `django-paypal` and other modules but I wasn't able to fully understand the process of handling a webhook.

I'm getting a `405 Error` in my console when I'm completing a payment.

I have successfully created a paypal sandbox account for testing purposes ( two user accounts were automatically created on it for tests ).

In my `settings.py`:

```
PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL = "the email"
PAYPAL_IDENTITY_TOKEN = "_BB3dqp-crOrUo2uh84g0zN2alX0LwWPAT85r0g-2Eo0"
```

In my `index.html`:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="my_email" id="id_business" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1" id="id_amount" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Subscription Package" id="id_item_name" />
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="website/page" id="id_notify_url" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="website/page" id="id_cancel_return" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="website/page" id="id_return_url" />
    <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="UID" id="id_invoice" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" id="id_cmd" />
    <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" id="id_charset" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" id="id_currency_code" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" id="id_no_shipping" />
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Buy it Now" />
</form>
```

And my `views.py`:

```
class PayPalWebhook(View):
    @staticmethod
    def post(request):
        event_json = json.loads(request.body)

        print '=========='
        print event_json.type
        print '=========='
        print event_json

        return HttpResponse(status=200)

class PaypalAPI(View):
    @staticmethod
    def post(request):
        pass
```

- shall I pass anything in my `PaypalAPI` class in order to get my form working as it should ? ( for the moment it correctly sends the payment but it uses the values inside the form parameters and that's not what I want)
- how can I get rid of that 405 error ? What am I doing wrong ?( as a mention, I created a webhook in dashboard)

I would just like to see the webhooks in my console, that's all.

Comment: You might want to check out dj-webhooks: https://dj-webhooks.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ A lot of the heavy lifting has been done there.

Comment: Check This
[Paypal Webhook Integration with Sandbox in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74992415/11272002)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps: 405 is usually when the API/Endpoint you are calling is used with an incorrect method. For example using a POST for a HTTP Call which only supports GET or not using the correct endpoint.

Python SDKs are a good point to start with as well https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK

Also, its a good practice to not share any tokens in forums/QnA sites. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def PayPalReturnView(request):
    # Do something here
```

to the view that PayPal posts too. I think I got your problem right but anyway try adding more info: your urls for example which are crucial here.